# For how many integers $n$ is $n^6+n^4+1$ a perfect square?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations

**QUESTION**

For how many integers $n$ is $n^6+n^4+1$ a perfect square?

I am completely blank on how to start. Could anyone please provide tricks on how to get a start on such questions?

Thanks for any answers!

Comment: It is for $n=0$ and $2$

Comment: Yeah! It also includes -2..but the answer is correct!

Comment: Note:  $\sqrt{n^6+n^4+\frac14n^2}=n(n+\frac12)$

Comment: Not quite, @J.W. but that's certainly the right idea.

Comment: It should be pretty easy to show that $n$ can't be odd (check what digit the number ends with if $n$ is odd)

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3244865/square-valued-integer-polynomial)

Comment: Oh..i got it..thanks!..I wasn't able to find this when I reviewed my questions..

Comment: I found it with [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24n%5E6%2Bn%5E4%2B1%24&p=1); and I meant $n^\color{red}2(n+\frac12)$ in my comment above

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know this

Comment: Really I meant $n(n^\color{red}2+\frac12)$

Comment: after showing $n$ must be even, compute $\left(n^3+\frac{n}2-1\right)^2$ and $\left(n^3+\frac{n}2\right)^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$n^6 + n^4 + 1 = n^6 + n*n^3 + 1=n^6 + 2\frac n2*n^3 + \frac {n^2}4 +(1-\frac {n^2}4) =(n^3 + \frac n2)^2 + (1-\frac {n^2}4)$

So if $n\ge 2$ then $n^6 + n^4 + 1 \le (n^3 + \frac n2)^2$ with equality holding only if $n = 2$.

And $(n^3 +\frac {n}2 - 1)^2 =(n^3 +\frac {n-2}2)^2 = n^6 + (n-2)n^3 + \frac {n^2-4n -4}4=n^6 + n^4 - 2n^3 + \frac {n^2}4 -n -1<n^6+n^4-n-1 < n^6 + n^4 + 1$.

So if $n \ge 2$ then $(n^3 +\frac {n-2}2)^2 < n^6 + n^4 + 1 \le (n^3+\frac {n}2)^2$  (with equality holding only if $n  =2$).

So if $n^6 + n^4 + 1$ is a perfect square then either $n=2$ and $n^6+n^4 + 1 = (n^3 +1)^2 = 9^2 = 81$....

or...

$n$ is odd and $n^6 + n^4 + 1 = (n^3 + \frac {n-1}2)^2$... which would mean $n^6 + n^4 + 1 = n^6 + (n-1)n^3 + (\frac{n-1}2)^2$ or in other words:

$n^3 -(\frac {n-1}2)^2 + 1=0$

$4n^3 - n^2 + 2n +3 = 0$

By rational root theorem the only integer larger than $2$ that could work would be $3$ and ... it doesn't.

Now $n^6 + n^6 + 1= (-n)^6 + (-n)^6 + 1$ so if $n$ is a solution if and only if $-n$ is a solution and $n = \pm 2$ is the only solution where $|n| \ge 2$.

So just need to check if $n = \pm 1, 0$.

$n=0$ yields $n^6 + n^4 + 1 = 0 = 1^2$ but $n=\pm 1$ yields $n^6 + n^4 + 1 = 3$ which is not a perfect square.

So $n=\pm 2$ and $n =0$ are the only three integers that yield perfect squares.

Answer (score 5):

### Greetings

Dear @binarybitarray, if you see this post helpful, vote it up. I think I could point out that your equation has only 3 solutions being $0,2,-2$

### Solution to your question

Because the degrees of all factors in this sum are even, I may solve this question for **natural numbers**

First, it is easy to point out that if $n$ is odd, then $n^6 + n^4 + 1 \equiv 3 \pmod {8}$. However, a perfect square can only have a remainder of 0,1,4 upon its division for 8, therefore it is a contradiction.

Thus $n$ is even, set $n=2m$ and $n^6 + n^4+ 1 = (2k+1)^2$

$ \Rightarrow 64m^6 + 16m^4+1 = 4k^2+4k+1$

$\Rightarrow 16m^6+4m^4=k^2+k$

$\Rightarrow 16m^6+4m^4= k(k+1)$

At this point, we may see that either $k$ is divisible by 4 or $k+1$ is.

**Case I: $k$ is divisible by 4**
Set $k=4q$, then we have

$16m^6+4m^4=4q(4q+1)$

$ \Rightarrow 4m^6+m^4= 4q^2 +q $

$ \Rightarrow m^4(4m^2+1)=q(4q+1)$

If m and q shares a prime divisor, it is easy to imply from $4m^6+m^4= 4q^2 +q $
that $v_p(q)=4v_p(m)$

If m and (4q+1) shares a prime divisor, it is easy to imply from $ m^4(4m^2+1)=q(4q+1)$ that $v_p(4q+1)=4v_p(m)$

Thus, $(4m^2+1) \ge m^3 \Rightarrow m \le 2$.

- Apply $m=2$ we have $n=4$, which is not a solution.
- Apply $m=1$ we have $n=2$, which is a solution.
- Apply $m=0$ we have $n=0$, which is a solution

**Case II: 4k+1 is divisible by 4**,

Then $m^4 (4m^2+1)=q(4q-1)$

Using the same solving strategy as above we are guaranteed to also have $n=0$ or $n=2$

### Commentaries on your question about stategies...

In a personal perspective, I think this is a pretty complicated question because of two things:

1. The degree of $n$ is $6$ and $4$, because 6 is not $4\times 2$ we cannot factorize the sum.
2. Also about the degree, if it is in the form $x^{3k+1}+x^{3q+2}+1$ then we can still factorize it. But that does not happen here.

Therefore, as far as I have been practicing on those problem, I think the most common strategy is to **reduce the equation to as simple as possible, and then use inequalities to limit the number of possible values of the variable.**

You can try applying it next time to see if it works.

Regards

Comment: What do you mean by $v_p$?

Comment: It's the p-adic valuation. if p|a, then $v_p(a)$ is the power of p in the prime factorization of a.

Answer (score 3):

Let $m$ and $n$ be integers such that $m^2=n^6+n^4+1$.  Without loss of generality, we may assume that $m$ and $n$ are nonnegative.  Clearly, $(m,n)=(1,0)$ is the only solution when $n\in\{0,1\}$.

If $n\ge 2$, then $n^2\geq 4$, so that $$(2n^3+n)^2=4n^6+4n^4+n^2\geq  4n^6+4n^4+4=4m^2\,.$$  On the other hand, $$\begin{align}4n^3-n^2+2n+3&\geq 8n^2-n^2+2n+3=7n^2+2n+3\\&\geq 7\left(n+\frac{1}{7}\right)^2+\frac{20}{7}\geq \frac{20}7>0\,,\end{align}$$
whence
$$\begin{align}(2n^3+n-1)^2&=4n^6+4n^4-4n^3+n^2-2n+1\\&<4n^6+4n^4+4=4m^2\,.\end{align}$$
Therefore, $$(2n^3+n-1)^2<(2m)^2\leq (2n^3+n)^2\,.$$
Ergo, $4n^6+4n^4+4=(2m)^2=(2n^3+n)^2$, which means $(m,n)=(9,2)$.

With signs involved, there are in total $3$ possible values of integers $n$: $-2$, $0$, and $+2$.  The equation $m^2=n^6+n^4+1$ has $6$ solutions $(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$: $(\pm 1,0)$ and $(\pm 9,\pm 2)$.

Answer (score 3):

The trivial solution $n=0$ is seen by inspection.

For $n \ne 0$, $y^2=n^6+n^4+1 \Rightarrow (y+1)(y-1)=n^6+n^4$.

Now $(y+1)-(y-1)=2 \wedge \gcd{(y+1),(y-1)}=1,2$ so we must resolve $n^6+n^4$ into two factors that differ by $2$ and have at most one factor of $2$ in common.

The factors $n^4,(n^2+1)$ are relatively prime, but $n^4-(n^2+1)=2$ has no solutions in the integers.

The factors $n^2,n^2(n^2+1)$ have $n^2$ as their $\gcd$, which is permissible only if $n=1$, but $n=1$ does not solve the original equation.

The factors $n^3,n(n^2+1)$ have $n$ as their $\gcd$, which is permissible if $n=1$ which we have already ruled out, or $n=2$, which solves the original equation. Noting that the original equation has $n$ in even powers, the solution $-2$ is also admitted because $(-2)^{2k}=2^{2k}$.

For completeness, we can look at $n=cd$ to see whether factoring $n^6+n^4$ might be done in any other way. However, $d=1$ changes nothing, and $d>2$ is not permitted, so we are constrained to examine $n=2c$. Also, that factor of $2$ can occur at most once in one of the factors of $n^6+n^4$, so we look at the factorizations $8c^4,2(4c^2+1)$ and $2c^4, 8(4c^2+1)$

After dividing through by $4$, $8c^4-2(4c^2+1)=2 \Rightarrow 2c^4-2c^2=1$ which is impossible because the difference of two even numbers is never $1$.

After dividing through by $2$, $2c^4- 8(4c^2+1)=2 \Rightarrow c^4-16c^2-5=0$. If we treat this as a quadratic equation in $c^2$, we derive $c^2=8\pm \sqrt{69}$ which is not an integer. So alternative factorings of $n$ do not change the outcome.

Solutions are $\{0,\pm2\}$

Comment: This was a great solution.. but I didn't get the point where you showed the 'completeness' of the proof.. I mean, when you write $n=2c$, why do you say that the factor $2$ can occur atmost once$?$.. and will that not be $8c^4,2c(4c^2+1)$ $?$

Comment: However you factor $n^6+n^4$, that factorization must be representable as $(y+1)(y-1)$. The factors of that product differ by $2$ and if they are even, represent two consecutive even numbers. For any two consecutive even numbers, one of them contains only a single factor of $2$.