# Square numbers in the form of $n^6 + n^4 +1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, square-numbers

> For what natural numbers is $n^6 + n^4 +1$ is a square of a natural number?

I just want to know if my way of solving it is correct or not. (I have checked the other threads regarding the same question but their answers have a different method than mine)

#### Here's what I did:

$$n^6 + n^4 +1 = n^6 + n^3\cdot n +1$$
$$=n^6 + \frac{2n^3\cdot n}{2} + 1$$
$$=n^6 + 2n^3\cdot \frac{n}{2} +1$$

This expression would be in the form of $(n^3 + 1)^2$ if $\frac{n}{2}=1$ and it would be in the form of $(n^3-1)^2$ if $\frac{n}{2}=-1$.  Since $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $n=+2$

Is the way I did correct? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For how many integers $n$ is $n^6+n^4+1$ a perfect square?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3578247/for-how-many-integers-n-is-n6n41-a-perfect-square)

Comment: @JitendraSingh, Yes I went through that thread, I just want to know if my solution is correct or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really say it would be the in form of $(n^3+1)^2$. Instead you have to show this.

So let this be in form of $(an^3+b)^2$

$$ a^2n^6+b^2+2abn^3=n^6+ 1 + n^4$$

If we compare coefficients,

$$ a^2n^6=n^6 => a=1 $$

$$ b^2=1 => b=1 $$

See we have neglected the $-1$ value for b because $-1$ isn't natural.

Now if we compare the last coefficent,

$$ 2abn^3=n^4 $$

$$ 2n^3=n^4 $$

$$ n=2$$

Comment: Does this answer your question or do you have any doubts?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: This is not correct: you implicitly assume the form $(an^3+b)^2$. The equality $1+n^4+n^6=f(n)^2$ need not hold as formal polynomials but only in value, so there is no reason to assume a particular form for $f(n)$. All you're given is that $f(n)\in\Bbb Z$, nothing more.

Comment: It is just an equality or equation not a polynomial

Comment: @JitendraSingh: My point is that there is no reason to expect it to be of the form $(an^3+b)^2$. All you can use is that it is of the form $f(n)^2$ and $f(n)$ is an integer (better to just say finding integer solutions to the diophantine equation $1+n^4+n^6=k^2$; no explicit relation between $n$ and $k$). Your approach is essentially verification like the one by OP and not a _proof_.